# EL comparison with equalIgnoreCase

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, el

How to check equalIgnoreCase in EL?

```
String a = "hello";
a.equalsIgnoreCase("hello");
```

Now on JSP page..

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{patientNotePrescriptionVar.prescriptionSchedule ==  patientNotePresBackingBean.sendPrescription}">
            ... Some code here ....
</h:panelGroup>
```

Is there any way to compate `patientNotePresBackingBean.sendPrescription` as equalIgnoreCase?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're using EL 2.2 (part of Servlet 3.0) or JBoss EL, then you should be able to just invoke that method in EL.

```html
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{patientNotePrescriptionVar.prescriptionSchedule.equalsIgnoreCase(patientNotePresBackingBean.sendPrescription)}">
```

If you're not on EL 2.2 yet, then your best bet is passing both strings through [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`fn:toLowerCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/toLowerCase.fn.html) (or [`fn:toUpperCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/toUpperCase.fn.html)) and then comparing it.

```html
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{fn:toLowerCase(patientNotePrescriptionVar.prescriptionSchedule) == fn:toLowerCase(patientNotePresBackingBean.sendPrescription)}">
```

Better, however, would be to not make them case sensitive. If they represent some kind of constants, better make them enums or something.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, but in this case as well adarshr's answer even it gives error like `The attribute prefix fn does not correspond to any imported tag library`

Comment: You of course need to declare the `fn` taglib in top of your JSP (exactly like as you did for JSF `h` taglib). Check the documentation for exact syntax: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html

Comment: No, it starts with `fn:`, not with `c:`.

Answer (score 5):

You could convert both the operands to lowercase and then equate them.

In case of JSTL, I would do

```
fn:toLowerCase(patientNotePrescriptionVar.prescriptionSchedule) eq fn:toLowerCase(patientNotePresBackingBean.sendPrescription)
```

Just check if you can do something similar in JSF. I've been out of touch of JSF of late, sorry.

Comment: If I was not wrong, you first answered something entirely different? I would otherwise not have posted a duplicate answer.

Comment: No, I just answered the first line and then later on added the JSTL example :) Besides, yours isn't a duplicate. It supplements my answer.

Comment: It gave an error... 
The attribute prefix **fn** does not correspond to any imported tag library